# Why tensions are equal in case of a smooth ring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram, string

As title says whats the reason behind it.

[image]

Lets say a string is tied at A and B and at C a smooth ring is in equilibrium.

How the both tensions would be equal?

Comment: It's not that the two tensions are equal. There is only one tension in one string.

Answer (score 1):

This question is a variation on the [capstan problem](http://ocw.abu.edu.ng/courses/physics/8-01sc-classical-mechanics-fall-2016/readings/MIT8_01F16_example8.11.pdf) where the difference between the two tensions is shown to be $T_2=T_1 e^{\mu \theta}$.

[image]
However, in this case the ring is smooth, $\mu=0$,  thus $T_2 = T_1e^0=T_1$.

The reason is that because the ring is smooth it cannot exert a (frictional) force at a tangent to the string and hence change the tension within it.

Since the only other forces acting on the ring, weight of ring and hanging weight,  exert vertical forces the ring will "slide" to the left until the position of static equilibrium is reached when the two tension forces are vertical mirror images of one another.
Thus, the system is not in a state of static equilibrium as shown in your diagram.
That can only be so if the ring is attached, stuck/knotted to the ring.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the coordinate system associated with the ring. 
Say, we sit on the ring and observe the string passing through.
Let's say, I fixed the ring somehow and I'm measuring $T_{\text{left}}$ and $T_{\text{right}}$.
What happens if the string on the right is more tightly stretched than on the left and I release it from being hold?
Obviously, we will see how the string is being pulled from the left to the right through the ring.
The right part of the string simply "overpowers" the left part.
Thus, if the ring is in equilibrium, you might be pretty sure that the tension on the right is equal to the tension on the left
$$
T_{\text{left}} = T_{\text{right}}.
$$

You may get even a step further with the idea of equilibrium -- use it to show that $x$ components of tensions are
$$
\left(\vec{T}_{\text{left}}\right)_x = 
-\left(\vec{T}_{\text{right}}\right)_x,
$$
while using the previously derived equality of their modules and that $\vec{w} = \vec{T}_{\text{left}} + \vec{T}_{\text{right}}$ derive that
$$
\left(\vec{T}_{\text{left}}\right)_y = 
\left(\vec{T}_{\text{right}}\right)_y =
-\frac{1}{2}(\vec{w})_y.
$$
Considering geometry of the problem, this means that the ring will be in equilibrium near the midpoint of the string.
Moving the ring to the left or to the right creates forces that are trying to return the ring to the midpoint.